# Parsing an XML file with PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-2.0

One of my application is generating below XML file.

```
<root>
    <command name="Set">
        <property name="PWR.WakeupOnLAN" value="6" errorcode="0x0"/>
    </command>
    <command name="Set">
    </command>
    <command name="biossettings">
        <property name="task" value="Succeeded." errorcode="0x0"/>
    </command>
</root>
```

I am interested in reading the value and errorcodes of "PWR.WakeupOnLAN" property name. Before posting here, I tried various things but couldn't find correct code for reading properties in powershell. Can any one help me with powershell code for this?

Comment: Please mark the correction answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In PowerShell 2.0 you can solve this using the new [Select-Xml](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347617.aspx) cmdlet and an [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) expression:

```
[xml]$document = "<root><command name='Set'><property name='PWR.WakeupOnLAN' value='6' errorcode='0x0'/></command><command name='Set'></command><command name='biossettings'><property name='task' value='Succeeded.' errorcode='0x0'/></command>"

$value = (Select-Xml -Xpath "//property[@name='PWR.WakeupOnLAN']/@value" $document).Node.Value
$errorCode = (Select-Xml -Xpath "//property[@name='PWR.WakeupOnLAN']/@errorcode" $document).Node.Value
```

**Related resources:**

- [Select-Xml](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347617.aspx)
- [Processing XML with PowerShell](http://thepowershellguy.com/blogs/posh/archive/2007/12/30/processing-xml-with-powershell.aspx)
- [XmlDocument Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx)
- [XmlAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

@Enrico Campidoglio gives the "cleanest" solution here is a kind of old fashion.

```
PS> $xml = [XML](get-content c:\temp\yourfile.xml)
PS> $errcode = ($xml.root.command | where {$_.property.name -eq "PWR.WakeupOnLAN" }).property.errorcode
```

Comment: +1 for backwards compatibility. Your example will work in both PowerShell 1.0 and 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility, is to create a function. Similar to JPBlanc's solution.

```
function Get-Info ($name='PWR.WakeupOnLAN', $targetXml){
    $properties = $targetXml.GetElementsByTagName("property") 
    $properties | Where {$_.Name -eq $name}
}

Get-Info -targetXml $xml
Get-Info -name Task -targetXml $xml
```

Comment: @all
Thanks for the answers. These really helped me.